# Delete items from linked list causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

I have an issue where I am trying to delete an entry from a linked list but it causes a segmentation fault no matter where I try to delete the item from (head, middle, or tail). I'm not sure where the issue lies.

```
    void
    add_to_list(struct linked_list *list, int x)
    {
        struct node *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
        n->data = x;
        n->next = NULL;
        if (list->head == NULL)
            list->head = n;
        if (list->tail != NULL)
            list->tail->next = n;
        list->tail = n;
    }
    void
    remove_from_list(struct linked_list *list, int position)
    {
        struct node *current_node = list->head;
        struct node *previous_node = NULL;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < position; i++) {
            previous_node = current_node;
            current_node = current_node->next;
        }
        if (position == 0) {    // removing the head means we have to
                        // update the head pointer
            list->head = list->head->next;
        } else {
            previous_node->next = current_node->next;
        }
        free(current_node);
        if (list->tail == current_node) // remove the last element means
                    // updating the tail pointer
            list->tail = previous_node;
    }

    int
    main(void)
    {
        struct linked_list list = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };
        add_to_list(&list, 'h');
        add_to_list(&list, 'e');
        add_to_list(&list, 'l');
            add_to_list(&list, 'l');
            add_to_list(&list, 'o');
        remove_from_list(&list, 'e');
        add_to_list(&list, 's');
        print_list_rec(&list);  // print_nodes_rec(list.head)
        free_list(&list);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Are you making sure it reconnects the list? Main issue with linked list is when you delete a node, it points to null so make sure you have it linked

Comment: it could very well be your add method that's erroneous as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call

```
remove_from_list(&list, 'e');
```

specifies `'e'` as a position in the list.  The ascii value of `'e'` is 101; you have 5 items in the list.

`remove_from_list` iterates through the list `position` times without checking whether it has reached the end.

You need to change this to either have the caller pass the index they want to remove or, better, change the second argument to be the item value to search for and modify the `for` loop in `remove_from_list` to exit when it finds this value.

```
void remove_from_list(struct linked_list *list, int data)
{
    struct node *current_node = list->head;
    struct node *previous_node = NULL;
    while (current_node != NULL) {
        if (current_node->data == data) {
            break;
        }
        previous_node = current_node;
        current_node = current_node->next;
    }
    if (previous_node == NULL) { // removing the head means we have to
```

In either case, it'd be safer if `remove_from_list` also guarded against reading beyond the end of its list

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are not checking whether you've reached the end of the list, and you might be trying to free a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - it only hints at routes for debugging.  It would be better to post this as a comment instead.  Also, calling `free(NULL)` is well defined to be safe so that isn't the problem.